# How to share your rails app with Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm trying to set up a Facebook sharing option for a specific model within my rails application.

I tried using a gem but would rather implement this feature as directed from Facebook Developers.

**I have this code in my application.html.erb file:**

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=11111111111111";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**And this code in my show.html.erb file:**

```
    <div class="fb-share-button" 
        data-href="<%= request.host+request.fullpath %>"
        data-layout="button_count">
      </div>
```

**When I try to share a specific node:**

```
Server error

500
RELOADHIDE DETAILS
The website encountered an error while retrieving https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?   app_id=...&sdk=joey&u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbooks%2F1%2Fchapters%2F3%2Ftableofcontents%2Flocalhost%2Fbooks%2F1%2Fchapters%2F3%2Ftableofcontents%2F20&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

I'm assuming this is where the error presents itself `<%= request.host+request.fullpath %>` but I'm not sure how or what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= request.original_url %>` gives you the URL originally requested. However you should take care whenever you use a URL that originates from the client as it can potentially be used as an exploit path.

See:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss

Comment: I was able to get it to work with `<%= link_to 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+request.host+request.fullpath, target: :blank %>` does this exploit the path as well?